# What type of function is graphed here, and how do I find an equation for it?

Tags: graphing-functions

[image]

To me it looks like a reciprocal function mixed with a cubic function. I tried out x/((x+1)(x-4)) and it looks very close, but I can't figure out the correct transformations to apply. What is the best way to go about trying to find an equation for this?

Comment: It's hard to tell without more exact points than $(2,0)$ and $(0,2)$ and the asymptotes, but at least you have to change the numerator to $4(x-2)$ to match these.

Comment: Consider the partial fraction form. It's like $ A / (x+1) + B /(x-4) + C(x)$.   What is the polynomial $C(x)$? How can we determine $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your answer, our function should take the following form:

$$f(x)=\frac{a(x-b)}{(x+1)(x-4)}$$

Since $f(2)=0$, then $b=2$.

$$\implies f(x)=\frac{a(x-2)}{(x+1)(x-4)}$$

Since $f(0)=2$, then $a=4$. Therefore,

$$f(x)=\frac{4(x-2)}{(x+1)(x-4)}$$

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the horizontal asymptote (looks like) is $ y = 0$, so there are no quadratic or higher terms in the numerator.

Comment: That's correct--even quadratic terms can be outruled.

Comment: And as an aside, the denominator could even be of the form $(x+1)(x-4)^3$, which we can't necessarily rule out unless we have much more detail about the graph.